# Understanding npm's "skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module"

Tags: node.js, selenium, npm, protractor

I am trying to force the version of selenium-webdriver and protractor using npm's package.json for that purpose but I get the following error message:

```
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add lru-cache@2.7.0 node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/lru-cache
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add sigmund@1.0.1 node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/sigmund
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add async@0.9.2 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/async
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add aws-sign2@0.5.0 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/aws-sign2
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add delayed-stream@0.0.5 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/delayed-stream
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running move combined-stream@0.0.7 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/combined-stream
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running move forever-agent@0.5.2 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/forever-agent
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add form-data@0.1.4 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/form-data
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running move hoek@0.9.1 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/hoek
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running move boom@0.4.2 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/boom
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running move cryptiles@0.2.2 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/cryptiles
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running move http-signature@0.10.1 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/http-signature
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add minimatch@0.3.0 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/minimatch
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add glob@3.2.11 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/glob
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running move oauth-sign@0.3.0 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/oauth-sign
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add qs@0.6.6 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/qs
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add selenium-webdriver@2.44.0 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running move sntp@0.2.4 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/sntp
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add hawk@1.0.0 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/hawk
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add request@2.36.0 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/request
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add protractor@1.8.0 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running update form-data@0.2.0 node_modules/protractor/node_modules/form-data
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running update hawk@2.3.1 node_modules/protractor/node_modules/hawk
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running update qs@3.1.0 node_modules/protractor/node_modules/qs
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running update request@2.57.0 node_modules/protractor/node_modules/request
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running remove selenium-webdriver@2.48.2 node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver
npm WARN update-linked node_modules/selenium-webdriver needs updating to 2.48.2 from 2.44.0 but we can't, as it's a symlink
npm WARN update-linked node_modules/protractor needs updating to 3.0.0 from 1.8.0 but we can't, as it's a symlink
```

Can someone please explain what these error messages mean?

Comment: Could you please show the contents of `package.json` and, also, what `npm` version are you using? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Remove `node_modules` directory and type `npm install`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.